# Android Timer Example

Tags: android, timer, andengine, counter

I'm developing a game via Andengine for Android. There is a player on my game scene. When the player pass finish line(800,0), the game will end. So I wanna show every passed seconds to user on scene. And finally I wanna show how much time passed till the finish.
How can I do that?

I tried this but doen'T work:

```
TimerHandler timerHandler = new TimerHandler(0.1f, true, new ITimerCallback(){

           @Override
           public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
              time.setText(""+pTimerHandler.getTimerSeconds());
           }
       });
registerUpdateHandler(timerHandler);
```

Comment: `How can I do that?` Probably with some code. What have you tried already?

Comment: I wanna show the passed time in terms of seconds or miliseconds

Comment: getTimerSecondsElapsed()

Comment: OK I tried like this but the new problem is using this line:time.setText(""+pTimerHandler.getTimerSecondsElapsed()); When I try to set a value to time variable, a error occours: LogCat: s29.postimg.org/4422hhnhj/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

getTimerSeconds will tell you the duration of the TimerHandler.

You want to use

```
getTimerSecondsElapsed()
```

instead. It tells you the seconds elapsed. A would say the api is not super clear, but the TimerHander class itself is pretty simple. I got this answer by looking at the code for org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler. You can see what's goin on in the onUpdate() function.

Comment: OK I tried like this but the new problem is using this line:time.setText(""+pTimerHandler.getTimerSecondsElapsed()); When I try to set a value to time variable, a error occours:  LogCat:  http://s29.postimg.org/4422hhnhj/Capture.png

Comment: GetTimerSecondsElapsed is probably creating a string with more characters than what your text field can display, and so the error is getting thrown. Just pre-process your string to make sure it is not too long. Andengine TextFields do not like it when they have to display extra characters. But the short answer is that in some way that string is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The problem occurs when creating text object. It must be like that:

```
time = new Text(150, 400, resourcesManager.font, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", vbom);
```

I mean you have to set default value to it. So the default value is its maximum characters that it can show.!